# Does the Alcubierre drive use negative energy to compress space infront of it?

Tags: energy, spacetime, space, warp-drives

The contraction in most images looks like a gravity well.  Is it that you use negative energy to BOTH contract and expand space or positive and negative to contract (positive energy) and then expand with then negative energy?

Answer (score 2):

The geometry of the Alcubierre drive looks like this:

[image: Alcubierre Drive]

The exotic matter is arranged as a torus, and it compresses spacetime on one side and expands it on the other so the direction of motion is normal to the plane of the torus. No additional normal or exotic matter is required.

One of the lesser appreciated features of the drive should be immediately apparent from the drawing - the drive is symmetrical so how do we decide which way it moves? That's a good question, and the somewhat unsatisfactory answer is that the Alcubierre metric describes the system in motion and doesn't tell us how to get the thing moving in the first place. I've seen claims that by some manipulation of the metric you can show that it can be interpreted as multiplying the original velocity. So you choose the direction of motion by setting your spaceship in motion before you turn on the drive. There are more details [on the NASA web site](http://ntrs.nasa.gov/archive/nasa/casi.ntrs.nasa.gov/20110015936.pdf) if you fancy tackling the maths.